# android load local path html and swf file using webview

Tags: android

i have a html embeds a swf file

i write this to load the html file by webview :

```
mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myweb.html");
```

now i have a question , i wanna let the html embed a swf file , which also in the

eclipse project assets directory.

could anyone tell me what path should i set?  file:///android_asset/myswf.swf??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a relative path. If your HTML and SWF file resides in the same folder, use the SWF filename directly. (i.e. myswf.swf).